# Eloquent, pivot table data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got three tables routines, measurements and pools, their pivot table is measure_routine which also stores a pool_id which references a pool in the pools table. The setup looks like such:

routines:

```
id
value
date
time
emp_id (To reference which employee conducted the task)
```

measurements:

```
id
title
```

pools

```
id
name
```

and the pivot table, measure_routine:

```
routine_id
measure_id
pool_id
```

Thus far I have defined in my models:

Routine.php

```
class Routine extends Eloquent
{
        public function measurements
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Measurement', 'measure_routine', 'routine_id', 'measure_id', 'pool_id')->withPivot('pool_id');
        }
    }
```

Measurement.php

```
class Measurement extends Eloquent
{
    public function routines()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Routine', 'measure_routine')->withPivot('pool_id');
    }
}
```

Pool.php

```
class Pool extends Eloquent

{
    public function measurement_routine()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('measure_routine', 'pool_id');
    }
}
```

What I was wondering is how I would go about extracting the pool_id (or possibly the pool name from the pool table) using eloquent?

Currently I've tried using $data = Routine::has('measurements')->get() in the controller, and then trying {{ $data->pivot->pool_id }} in the view, but that resulted in a trying to get property of non-object error.

Comment: You can create a model to the linking table, if you haven't done yet.

Comment: As in create a model for the measure_routine pivot table ?

Comment: Yes, you create a model `RoutineHasMeasurements` let's say, this model will have a hasMany relationship to each of the other 3 models. Now you can also retrieve pool name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this (To get the first item from collection and pivot):

```
$data = Routine::has('measurements')->get();
$data->first()->measurements->first()->pivot->pool_id;
```

Because, `$data` is a collection of `Routine` returned by `get()` so the first item has another collection of `measurements`, so again to get the first `measurements` from the collection you may use `first()` again and then access the `pivot->pool_id`, so you may also use a loop in your `view` as well, something like this:

```
@foreach($data as $routine)
    {{ $routine->property }}
    @foreach($routine->measurements as $measurement)
        {{ $measurement->property }}
        {{ $measurement->pivot->property }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: By the way, any chance you'd know how I'd extract the name of the pool instead of the ID ?

Comment: You have to add `->withPivot('pool_id')->withPivot('name')`, another `->withPivot` after `->withPivot('pool_id')`.

Comment: If you use `->withPivot('name')` then you may access `->pivot->name` just like `pool_id`.

Comment: Seems like it tries to select measure_routine.name when I add the second withPivot and try to access it with $measurement->pivot->name within the foreach.

Comment: Yes, it'll show `measure_routine.name` because `withPivot` will add the name from `pools` in the `pivot` table.

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but this is what it throws me if I try 

('pools.name) - https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ix8efkpziaxurs/eloquent.png
('name') - https://www.dropbox.com/s/cqwf1tobt449h8e/eloquent2.png

Comment: You told before it was selecting `measure_routine.name` which means it worked before, right ?

Comment: It didn't work, because only the pool_id resides in measure_routine as a foreign key for pools where the name is ^^ It did work when I only tried to extract the pool_id though.

Comment: Did you use `->withPivot('pool_id')->withPivot('name')` ?

Comment: Yup, the error on the second screenshot is when I used that.

Comment: Was it like `return $this->belongsToMany('Measurement', 'measure_routine', 'routine_id', 'measure_id')->withPivot('pool_id')->withPivot('name');`, try this, copy and paste.

Comment: Still get the same error. ( On a side note, thanks for bothering to help this extensively :) )

Comment: It should work and I said most welcome so most welcome always :-)

Comment: I've worked with same kind of database tables relation and worked, practically proven, how it's not working ?